# Not getting Success Response from PayPal even after it is successful

Tags: .net, paypal, integration, response, payment

I have integrated the **PayPal Payment Gateway** on `midnightcake.com` for accepting payments online. Even we have received some of the payments from the customers, but there is one issue. Even if the payment is successfully done by customer, the response that is been sent to our website is '**invalid**' or '**failure**' instead of '**completed**' and '**verified**' therefore our website is showing the order as failure even after getting the payment from customer. Let me know what might be the reason for this? why am I not getting success response from PayPal? any errors in integration ? Our project is in `.NET`.

Comment: kindly put some relevent code for us to identify the error

Answer (score 0):

You may reach the Paypal MTS team to find the root cause for this specific issue.
MTS ticket submission link [here](https://www.paypal-techsupport.com/).